# What happens when if statement goes true (in this code)?

Tags: java, if-statement, logical-operators

There is a problem in codingbat.com which you're supposed to remove "yak" substring from the original string. and they provided a solution for that which I can't understand what happens when the if statement goes true!

```
public String stringYak(String str) {
  String result = "";

  for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
    // Look for i starting a "yak" -- advance i in that case
    if (i+2<str.length() && str.charAt(i)=='y' && str.charAt(i+2)=='k') {
      i =  i + 2;
    } else { // Otherwise do the normal append
      result = result + str.charAt(i);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

It just adds up i by 2 and what? When it appends to the result string?

Link of the problem:
https://codingbat.com/prob/p126212

Comment: What's the problem? the `if` statement is `true` when the found substring is "yak", then it will just add +2 to `i` in order to skip that word and continue the loop to find more yak's.

Comment: Presumably it's supposed to be checking the letter a as well

Answer (score 2):

The provided solution checks for all single characters in the input string. For this `i` is the current index of the checked character. When the current char is not a `y` and also the `(i+2)` character is not a `k` the current char index is advanced by 1 position.

Example:

```
yakpak
012345
i
```

So here in the first iteration the char at `i` is `y` and `i+2` is a `k`, so we have to skip 3 chars. Keep in mind `i` is advanced by 1 everytime. So i has to be increased by 2 more. After this iteration `i` is here

```
yakpak
012345
   i
```

So now the current char is no `y` and this char will get added to the result string.

But it's even simpler in Java as this functionality is build in with regex:

```
public String stringYak(String str) {
  return str.replaceAll("y.k","");
}
```

The `.` means every char.

Comment: Great explanation and an elegant alternative to solve this problem

Comment: So it jumps over the 'k' in for loop. thanks for explanation and for great alternate solution. (I still cant vote! :)))

Answer (score 0):

If `i` is pointing at a `y` and there is as `k` two positions down, then it wants to skip the full `y*k` substring, so it add `2` to `i` so `i` now refers to the `k`. WHen then loop continues, `i++` will skip past the `k`, so in effect, the entire 3-letter `y*k` substring has been skipped.